# Is requesting Axios auth header necessary in react.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I’m coding a MERN web app and I would like to know if it’s necessary request with axios my server and check if my auth header is valid in private routes. For example:

These are routes from my node.js server (Server.js):

```
app.get("/profile", auth.checkheader, user.UserProfile);
app.get("/", auth.checkheader, books.showBooks);
```

and this is the way I send my auth header with axios in one of the frontend views (Home.js):

```js
const user = (data) => {
  Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/profile", data, {headers: {auth: token}})
  .then(res => {
    if (data) {
      //Show some info user login
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle error logic
  })
}
```

Do I need to continue requesting my server to authenticate my tokens in the frontend? Is this necessary/the only way?

Comment: As ever, it really depends what you want to do / optimize for. In your case, when you say "token", what do you mean?

Comment: Token would be the user session´s token. Tokens  in my webapp are made with JWT and stored with redux. @sloppypasta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most scenarios, though it may not always be necessary, best practice is to validate the token on any API call to a "protected" endpoint. In most cases, the token is passed as part of the `Authorization` header, though there are other options.

There are different types of JWTs and different situations for using them. Signed JWTs allow you to verify the integrity of the token (whether it has been tampered with) while encrypted JWTs will allow you to hide the information contained within them. In my experience, signed JWTs are easier to setup, use, and debug. When used correctly (i.e., without carrying sensitive information) they are good enough for most situations. They can be signed either via a secret key or a public/private key pair.

I don't know which of the above types and situations applies to your server, but in general I would recommend verifying the authenticity of your JWTs on every request, or at minimum, on every request to a sensitive endpoint.

You can read more about JWTs and how/when to use/validate using these resources:

- [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction) (managed by Auth0/Okta)
- [Curity JWT Best
  Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/)
- [OWASP JWT Presentation](https://owasp.org/www-chapter-vancouver/assets/presentations/2020-01_Attacking_and_Securing_JWT.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like to ask if retrieve the  user ´s id from mongodb in my tokens is not a good idea @sloppypasta

Comment: The standard place to store the user's id is in the `sub` claim of the JWT payload. `sub` is one of the registered claims, which are recommended (but not required) in order facilitate compatibility across 3rd party providers. You can also create your own custom claims (e.g., many people add a user's email address as a custom claim). You can read more about all that [here](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-token-claims).